# How to use RETURNING clause in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, database

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.2 (it should be the minimum version supporting RETURNING), precisely 8.2.19 on GNU/Linux. I tried to use returning clause on automatically inserted column that is also constrained as primary key. The insertion of new row is correctly completed but the returned result is empty (verified with query executer in pgAdmin). I tried implicit insertion and also specifying DEFAULT for primary key column.

The column I tried to return is defined as

```
al_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval(('"allarmi_al_id_seq"'::text)::regclass)
```

and the insertion query is like

```
INSERT INTO alarms (al_id, al_descr) 
     VALUES (DEFAULT, 'description') 
  RETURNING al_id;
```

`allarmi_al_id_seq` is obviously (?) a sequence and is defined as

```
CREATE SEQUENCE allarmi_al_id_seq
    INCREMENT 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
    START 34564230
    CACHE 1;
```

What's wrong?

Comment: looks like it's working in 8.3.20 - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/309b9/1. Should be some fix between these 2 versions :)

Comment: Did you try it without expliciting the al_id? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/309b9/4

Comment: Yes, I was referring exactly to that style saying "implicit insertion"

Comment: Does it work `INSERT INTO alarms (al_descr) VALUES ('description')  RETURNING al_id;` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also explicitly read the current value of the sequence and return that:

```
INSERT INTO alarms (al_id, al_descr) 
     VALUES (DEFAULT, 'description') 
  RETURNING currval('allarmi_al_id_seq') AS al_id;
```

Note that the currval function returns the most recently obtained value in **this** session, so there are no concurrency issues (unless you have a trigger that causes the sequence to be incremented).